# Input any mathematical table without using loops

Tags: c#, string, math

I need to print mathematical table without using any loop (for, while, do while, etc.). Can anyone help me out, the easiest example I could find was writing console.writeline 10times for each line.

> This is my code!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Question4
{

 int product, i=1;
  public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  int num;
  Console.Write("Enter the Number to Print its Multiplication Table: ");
  num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("\nMultiplication Table For {0}: ",num);
  TableFunctionName (num);
   }
   public void TableFunctionName(int n)
  {
   if(i<=10)
  {
   table=n*i;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}",n,i,table);
    i++;
     }
   return;

     }

     }
```

Comment: What is a "mathematical table"? Why can't you use loops?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @gunr2171 I think OP means 'multiplication tables'

Comment: how about using recursion

Comment: like a table of 2, 3 or 4 or any number. I cant use loops because it is mentioned in the problem I am trying to solve!

Comment: @pm100 could you elaborate a little with some piece of code that would really help me out!

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what part of your code isn't working as you expect.  It would also be helpful if you give us an example of the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recursion

```
  static   void Multiply(int a, int b) {
        if (a > 1)
            Multiply(a - 1, b);
        Console.WriteLine($"{a} * { b} = {a * b}");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Multiply(10, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much this worked out for me! I edited the answer above for anyone with this problem!

Comment: Should I revert it back ?

Comment: @M.BurhanAhmad - I just did

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the Number to Print its Multiplication Table: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    var number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    
    CalculateAndPrint(number, 1);
}

static void CalculateAndPrint(int number, int factor)
{
    if (factor > 9) return;
    
    Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}", number, factor, number * factor);
    CalculateAndPrint(number, ++factor);
}
```